# Mudar a idade minima de um app já publicado na Apple Store

Tags: ios, app

Ola!

Estou com um problema, recentemente eu publiquei um app na Apple Store, mas acabei errando na hora de passar algumas informações sobre o app.

Então meu app ficou com rating 17+... porem o app pode ser baixado por usuários de 10+ ...

Como faço para mudar o rating do meu app?? (No caso isso seria a idade mínima para baixar o app)

Obrigado!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só pode mudar o rating do seu app submetendo uma nova versão dele. Isso é porque a Apple quer sempre validar se o rating assinalado esta de acordo com o conteúdo do app durante o review.

Se o campo fosse aberto, desenvolvedores poderiam lançar apps com conteúdo forte e rating 17+ e depois mudar para 4+ para alcançar mais público, por exemplo.

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo, precisei fazer uma update do app e consegui alterar o rating com esse procedimento! Obrigado!